# Paraview no longer opens .pvtu files (linux)

Tags: paraview

I'm having a problem loading .pvtu files and .vtu files in general. When I try to open a file in Paraview (5.10.0-RC1) i get a long list of error messages related to parsing XML files:

> ERROR: In ./VTK/IO/XMLParser/vtkXMLParser.cxx, line 375
> vtkXMLDataParser (0x6409b1932ce0): Error parsing XML in stream at line 43, column 0, byte index 3152: not well-formed (invalid token)

> ERROR: In ./VTK/IO/XML/vtkXMLReader.cxx, line 521
> vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader (0x6409b7b8f910): Error parsing input file.  ReadXMLInformation aborting.

> ERROR: In ./VTK/Common/ExecutionModel/vtkExecutive.cxx, line 752
> vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x6409bb197960): Algorithm vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader(0x6409b7b8f910) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (0x6409bb2fd7c0)
> Debug: Off
> Modified Time: 2196890
> Reference Count: 1
> Registered Events: (none)
> Request: REQUEST_INFORMATION
> ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
> FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0

This is repeated many times, pointing at different lines.

##### Troubleshooting

I have no idea what I'm doing differently from before, I could load the files without problems yesterday...

I have tried this:

1. I can load the files without problems on another setup / installation (my windows laptop).
2. I have tried removing Paraview completely and re-installng:

   - `$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove paraview`
   - `$ sudo apt-get update`
   - `$ sudo apt-get -y install paraview`

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4.

Is there something wrong with my paraview preferences for loading the file type?  Any help would be appreciated, new to posting on stack overflow!

#### Update (DATA)

I can open some simple .vtu files like this one:
(download) https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/vtu/triangle_mesh_linear.vtu

from the examples on the site: https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/vtu/vtu.html

I **can** open my own files on my windows laptop setup, but not on my ubuntu setup like I need to.

An example of my own files (same file two different links):

https://filetransfer.io/data-package/9e5q1xSF#link
or
https://file.io/rqkfG4YnaLuQ

###### Test:

The file opens fine in Glance:
https://kitware.github.io/glance/app/

Hope this helps!

#### Solved!

Installing latest binaries using [this guide](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md#linux) (if I understand that term correctly), I can now open my files.
Thank you @NicoVuaille

Comment: This is a stable reader from paraview, so problem comes much likely from your file. Please check with another file, and double check your file content. Then if it persists, share data please

Comment: I can open the file on other installations, i can open simple example files. Added data as requested @NicoVuaille

Comment: I have no issue to open your file here on linux, with 5.10.0 or dev version. You may want to use official binaries of the latest release instead of the ubuntu package https://www.paraview.org/download/

Comment: Thank you @NicoVuaille problem solved! Would you mind explaining what is the difference between installing a program with apt-get install, and make install a tar.gz file?
I don't understand why this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing latest binaries using [this guide](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md#linux), I can now open my files. Thanks to @NicoVuaille for the solution.

Steps taken:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove paraview  

$ sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libxt-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5help5 qttools5-dev qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev python3-dev python3-numpy libopenmpi-dev libtbb-dev ninja-build qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools


$ git clone --recursive https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview.git
$ mkdir paraview_build
$ cd paraview_build
$ cmake -GNinja -DPARAVIEW_USE_PYTHON=ON -DPARAVIEW_USE_MPI=ON -DVTK_SMP_IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE=TBB -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../paraview
$ ninja
```

And then running Paraview from `./bin/paraview`
Now the files open fine!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for feedback @KeyboardCat, I will make an edit.